# Android app for seeing pictures in a hierarchical way

Tags: android, photography

I believe there are a lot of app for seeing pictures on Android.

The app I'm looking for should be:

- free or cheap (<20$)
- mature, you can find a definition of what mature means [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/910056/196210)
- have a well finished graphic (comparable with the standard program for seeing
- **should allow to see ONLY the folders and not their subfolders **
- it should only show images and videos (not the other file type)
- it should preview the images exactly as the original one (with a thumbnail)

For hierarchical I mean that Android's default image gallery player shows **every** folder it can find. I mean it mixes together folder and subfolder. From the *root* you can access any folder. **I don't want this.**

I want some comparable app where you can open a folder and see immediate files inside that folder, but not deeper. I do not want an app that automatically combines the contents of the folder I am currently viewing with its subfolders. If I want to see the images in a subfolder, I will open the subfolder.

Do you know anything like this?

Comment: What I don't understand: *see ONLY the folder which are not inside the other folder* – in which "other folder"? And which folder? Also: Are all other folders "taboo", or would it be OK if you can "switch modes"? There are several gallery apps which can work "folder-based", i.e. like a file manager "walking the tree".

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean it should work folder-based like a file manager "walking the tree". It describes perfectly what I'm looking for. But I want this app just showing images and with a thumbnail preview as the original one..

Comment: "gerarchical" does not seem to be a word in modern English. Do you mean hierarchical? If not, please link to a definition of this word, thanks!

Comment: [Gerarchial](https://www.wordnik.com/words/gerarchy) is an outdated form of hierarchical. Just like the OP says "he" when referring to an app, not every word is perfect. I've edited the question to make the English a little clearer. @Sam, if I've gotten something wrong, please clarify.

Comment: yes, I meant hierarchical. Sorry english is not my native language. Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried just using a file manager, maybe one that shows thumbnails? In what way is that not a suitable solution?

Comment: @Caleb: yes, I've tried but it shows every file and it starts from wrong folder. It's not it's native use. I really hope to find an app similar to the original Gallerie of Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note: Please read the comments below this answer.  There have been some significant changes to these apps since this answer was posted.  Please perform additional research on these apps before deciding if you want to install them.*

For one, you could simply use a file explorer. I use **[ES File Explorer](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.estrongs.android.pop)**, which includes a picture viewer (amongst others):

- *Free or cheap:* Free
- *Mature:* Definitely. It's around for a long time, runs stable, never ever crashed on me or caused any trouble.
- *Well finished graphic:* Not sure how to define that, but pics look fine
- *Only show folders (not sub-folders):* If I understand that part of your requirement correctly, yes. It shows only the pics in the current folder; for pics of sub-folders you have to change into them.
- *Only show images & videos (not other files):* Being a file manager, it shows all files. So here you'd have to compromise. But you can switch to "image mode" (see screenshots) :)
- *Preview thumbnails:* Yes.
- *Hierarchical:* As a file manager, naturally.
  [image: ES File Explorer: image mode]
  <sup>*ES File Explorer:* Image mode (source: Google Play; click image for larger variant)</sup>

**[QuickPic](https://www.appbrain.com/app/com.alensw.PicFolder)** might be an alternative. It's some time ago I've used it last, but one of its features is to allow you browsing by folder. A detailed review can e.g. be found [here](https://tech.firstpost.com/reviews/quickpic-for-android-review-60493.html).

- *Free or cheap:* Free
- *Mature:* Definitely. It's around for a long time, runs stable. One of the fastest, smallest, and at the same time a feature-rich image viewer (and editor, btw).
- *Well finished graphic:* It's known for that, yes.
- *Only show folders (not sub-folders):* Again depending on my understanding of what you mean: Possible, yes (see screenshot).
- *Only show images & videos (not other files):* It's a picture browser, so yes (AFAIR; as said above, it's a while ago I've used it last).
- *Preview thumbnails:* Yes.
- *Hierarchical:* See screenshot.
  [image: QuickPic folder view]
  <sup>QuickPic: Explorer mode (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This Question maybe a bit older but i know an app which perfectly solves your Question.
[Cam Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sagar.mehar.camera2) *combines the ability of Gallery, File Manager & Camera.*

[image: CamStore] [image: CamStore]
<sup>*Cam Store* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sagar.mehar.camera2); click images for larger variants)</sup>

The first screenshot shows how the app corresponds to your wish of "hierarchival view". This app is still pretty new (just released in 1/2016), but well rated.

Comment: Please expand on how it perfectly solves this question.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Answers must show how the product matches the requirements, and what makes it recommendable (preferably personal experience). I've added some details so I don't have to delete your answer. Could you please fill the gaps I left?